# Entity Framework - Include two levels deep selected properties

Tags: asp.net, select, frameworks, include, entity

The entity framework provides navigation elements for foreign keys. If you use lazy loading, the navigation elements have NULL values otherwise .Include loads the entire object

```
ObjectA = await _context.ObjectA.Include(b => b.ObjectBNavigation)
```

What if the navigation element is large and you need only Name property? Then you need to additionaly use .Select and create a new object that contains the properties you need

```
ObjectA = await _context.ObjectA
.Include(b => b.ObjectB)
.Select(b => new ObjectA() 
{
    Name = b.Name,
    ObjectBNavigation = new ObjectB() { Name = b.ObjectBNavigation.Name },
})
.ToListAsync();
```

Now you can display element Name insted of element Index

```
@if(item.ObjectA != null)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ObjectBNavigation.Name)
```

And the Index page loads in an instant. I hope this will be helpfull for other ASP.NET newbies like me.

```
public partial class ObjectA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int? ObjectBId { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectB? ObjectBNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class ObjectB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
```